# why do you need to compile a keras / tensorflow model that was loaded from a saved copy?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss

I understand how you save model and weights files and load them back up. I don't understand why the compilation with optimizers

```
loaded_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
score = loaded_model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
```

Since you are no longer during gradient descent, why do you need the loss function and optimizer?

Comment: This does not look like "pure" TF to me. Are you using Keras?

Comment: beg your pardon. I am going thru keras.